# ack regex logical OR

Tags: linux, regular-expression, ack

I want to ignore the file if the filename match any of these  words : copy, cony, coby OR tool, trol, thol etc.

This one works :

```
ack -l -i --ignore-file=match:/co.y/ --ignore-file=match:/t.ol/ "mystring" _mynukelib
```

But i want to use single --ignore parameter. I tried to use "|" to create "OR" logic like in normal regex but doesn't work :

```
ack -l -i --ignore-file=match:/co.y|t.ol/ "mystring" _mynukelib
```

What is the proper syntax to perform logical OR.

Comment: Simply escape pipe `\|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the `ignore` switch work against multiple regexes, use curly braces and commas.

```
ack -l -i --ignore-file=match:{t.ol,co.y} "mystring" _mynukelib
```

That will ignore any files in the `_mynukelib` directory with names that the regexes of `co.y` or `t.ol` even if they contain `mystring`.

To exclude other regexes (or strings), simply add them into to curly braces separated by commas. `ack` uses the brace expansion of the `bash` shell which is probably what you are using. It works in the same way.

Comment: Hi sorry i made a mistake , i've edited my questions, I need to put the regex pattern , not the fix pattern. So i can't use { } and , to combine them.

Comment: @andio Did you actually try it with curly braces? They work with both regexes and fixed strings. See my update.

Comment: Ahh, i might not get enough sleep. I tried before it didn't work and now it works. ...Thanks a lot.